# Unity3d c# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

> ` public class Shoot : MonoBehaviour {

```
 public GameObject shell;
 public Transform barrelEnd;
 public float launchForce = 200;

 void Update () {

     if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
     {
         Fire();
     }
 }
 void Fire()
 {
     Rigidbody projectile;
     projectile = Instantiate(shell, barrelEnd.position, barrelEnd.rotation) as Rigidbody;
     projectile.AddForce(0, 0, launchForce);

 }
}
```

In Unity3d, all I want to do is instantiate a shell and launch it. When I play, it will instantiate the shell but it does not launch it, it just drops. I don't understand why I keep getting this error. Clearly i've already created an instance of an object correct? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: does it give the error or does is instantiate the shells or both? If if gives you the error then it should not instantiate anything. Can you give us more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you are not instantiating a `Rigidbody`, you are instantiating a `GameObject` which contains a `Rigidbody` as a component.

When you use `as` and you try to cast it to something that the object is not it sets the cast `null`. Change the cast to a `GameObject`, then use [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) to get the `Rigidbody` and it should work.

```
projectile = Instantiate(shell, barrelEnd.position, barrelEnd.rotation) as GameObject;
Rigidbody rb = projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
rb.AddForce(0, 0, launchForce);
```

Answer (score 2):

This error can appear for many reasons.

Make sure that `shell` and `barrelEnd` are assigned in the Editor. If that is done then you need to getComponent from the Object you just instantiated.

Unless you camera is **always** facing the Z axis, there would be a problem in this line of code `projectile.AddForce(0, 0, launchForce);`.

If this is an FPS game with camera that moves around, use `cameraTransform.forward` to make the bullet always shoot forward/away from the camera.

```
public GameObject shell;
public Transform barrelEnd;
public float launchForce = 200;

Transform cameraTransform;

void Start()
{
    cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;
}

void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        Fire();
    }
}
void Fire()
{
    GameObject tempObj;
    tempObj = Instantiate(shell, barrelEnd.position, barrelEnd.rotation) as GameObject;
    Rigidbody projectile = tempObj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    projectile.velocity = cameraTransform.forward * launchForce;
}
```

Comment: We know `shell` is ok because it does create a new shell inside the player, however good point about `barrelEnd` overlooked that one. However I disagree with using the camera's forward, `barrelEnd.forward` seems more like the logical choice.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the forward direction. This was also an issue

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have values for `shell` and `barrellEnd`. You either can do that from the unity editor or in your start function from code
2. before calling `rb.AddForce(0, 0, launchForce);` check if `rb` is `null` or not. If null, Scott's approach will make more sense.